# Different rendering in Chrome based on whether a page is refreshed with F5 or Return?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Try opening this [page](http://stats.ioinformatics.org/chrome.html) in Chrom[e/ium]. Then, if you focus on the address bar and press Return, the page is rendered as expected:

[image: behaviour after pressing Return]

If, however, you press F5 or Ctrl+F5, the page is rendered incorrectly:

[image: behaviour after pressing F5]

The source code of the page doesn't change, and there is no JavaScript involved. This effect can be reproduced 100% of the time in Chromium 39.0.2171.65 on Linux and Chrome 39.0.2171.71 on Windows.

Why?

Comment: looks like 'font-family: Electrolize;' is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `float: left` at `.countrydata` on `design.css:272` is having a wrong calculation.

You can avoid it by removing the floating and using `display: inline-block`, this way the content will have just the needed size, but wont float. If you really need it to `float`, I recommend setting the default `width` to the desired size.